# for loops on text files

Tags: python, list, filenames

I'm writing a huge code and one of the little things I need it to do is go over a text file that is divided to different lines.
i need it to create a new list of lines every time the line is empty. for example if the text is: (each number is a new line)

1
2
3
4

5
6
3

1
2

it should build 3 different lists: [1,2,3,4], [5,6,3], [1,2]

this is my code so far (just getting started):

> ```
>     new_list=[]
>     my_list=[]
>     doc=open(filename, "r")
>     for line in doc:
>             line=line.rstrip()
>             if line !="":
>                     new_list.append(line)
>     return new_list
> ```

Comment: Regarding the comment by @jdi, You can learn more about [how/why to accept answers from this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @jdi i'm sorry, i didn't know how to do it, i'm new here.. thank you - done :)

Comment: @Yarden: Thanks! No worries. Its good that you figured it out. Makes people much more inclined to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, This should work now:

```
initial_list, temp_list = [], []
for line in open(filename):
    if line.strip() == '':
        initial_list.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = []
    else: temp_list.append(line.strip())
if len(temp_list) > 0: initial_list.append(temp_list)
final_list = [item for item in initial_list if len(item) > 0]
print final_list
```

Comment: can you please explain how does it start a new list when the line is empty?

Comment: `if line.strip() != ''` makes it only add to the list if the line is not empty

Comment: I see what you're saying now, this code doesnt work for that. Give me a sec and i'll see if i can make it work

Comment: @Yarden Try this code now, it should work. I tested it with a file and it seems to be working.

Comment: Ohhh my bad, i read your entire question again. I'm sorry, hang on i'll try and fix it

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
[x.split() for x in fileobject if x.strip()]
```

To get integers, you could use `map`:

```
[map(int,x.split()) for x in fileobject if x.strip()]
```

where `fileobject` is the object returned by `open`.  This is probably best to do in a context manager:

```
with open(filename) as fileobject:
     data_list = [map(int,x.split()) for x in fileobject if x.strip()]
```

---

Reading some of the comments on the other post, it seems that I also didn't understand your question properly.  Here's my stab at correcting it:

```
with open(filename) as fileobject:
    current = []
    result = [current]
    for line in fileobject:
        if line.strip(): #Non-blank line -- Extend current working list.
            current.extend(map(int,line.split()))
        else:  #blank line -- Start new list to work with
            current = []
            result.append(current)
```

Now your resulting list should be contained in `result`.